# Receiving a bad grade from close professor?

Tags: phd, masters, grades

Hello I am doing my masters and I got relatively bad grade from a professor. I am going to do another project with him in this semester. I think I deserve a better grade but the problem is that only way to re-evaluate my report is to make a complaint to study committee or to dean. My professor is a very nice person and he is one of the best in the area may be the best,and our communication is good he even wrote "look forward to seeing you". He was very satisfied with my lab. work but I messed up writing report, because he said that I should not write lots of theory but now one of the evaluation report says I should have write more theory(He is not the only evaluator, there are 2 more sensors who I dont know). It's so sad that I got a bad result, but I also don't want to lose healthy connection with the professor. I am doing my masters one of the best universities in Europe and I want to do Phd after my masters so grade is important for me and also recommendation is important for me. I dont know what to do, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you questioning the grade?

Comment: @user2768 It is important for me to apply to Phd programs, I've done 2 times more work than I should for the project, I feel really sad about it. My work is good but the only evaluation criteria is the report.

Comment: "I am doing my masters one of the best universities in Europe" - I always wonder  what metric people use to determine that.

Comment: @existenceisfutile Why do you feel that you deserve a higher grade? Put another way, what did the professor get wrong then they marked your assignment?

Comment: @problemofficer One of Oxford, Cambridge, or Imperial, source: https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2018/world-ranking

Comment: Resistance is not.

Comment: My suggestion would be to do a great job on the project with him this semester, including the write up.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that a good grade is worthy (every student wants a nice grade). However, it is not uncommon to score somehow “poorly” while you expect the best result. So, if your results are contrary to your expectations and if you have reason to believe that what you earned is not what you deserve (in the sense of your achievements in exams, presentations, written reports, etc), you may need to take some course of action as per your university’s rules and regulations.

I think, a useful first step would be to ask your professor to show you how you have been graded and what you did right and what you did wrong. That would also be a good opportunity to learn from your mistakes (if any). You may also have the opportunity to discover if there were any mistakes on the side of your professor in evaluating (correcting) your report. After talking to your professor, if you are convinced that the grade you got is what you deserve, then you have to accept that and learn from  the things you didn’t do well. If, with your discussion with the professor, you find out things necessitating revision of your marks (re-grading), that would be accomplished as per your university’s rule. If you still cannot resolve the issue after discussing with your professor, you may follow your university’s formal appealing procedures. But when you do so, have a convincing reason for why you are questioning your  grade. How much time you have devoted on the work or the fact that you need a good grade to pursue a PhD, I think, are not reasons strong enough to justify appealing. What is it that you correctly did but for which did not earn the deserved mark? Such things should be at hand. (I feel many things vary from university to university, but this is what I think you could consider).

Comment: +1. I would stress a bit more asking if it is possible to make corrections and resubmit for regrading. Some professors permit this as a matter of course. For others it would be unusual, even impossible. But it is worth asking after taking the other steps suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look for others ways to improve your reporting and at the end show that you have improved this skill from then on. Of course, your professor will also mention this in the recommendation letter, so even if your grade was lower from that course, it will be compensated, I guess.

However, you should be more careful about reporting, really. If you do extremely good work but poor at reporting it well, no one will comprehend the significance of your work and your reputation will not be even half worth of your actual value.

Good planning -> good conduct -> good report.